# GHC: statically linking Linux binaries for ARM & MIPS processors

Tags: haskell, arm, mips, ghc, static-linking

I am using Debian/MIPS+QEMU to build [MIPS ports of PortFusion](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion/wiki/MIPS-Builds) (a TCP tunneling solution). The resulting binaries are linked against GNU libc. Thus, they cannot be just copied over and used on vanilla OpenWrt which ships with **uclibc** instead of **eglibc** (which seems binary-compatible with GNU libc).

---

- Can GHC 7.4 not statically link libc (+ libgmp, etc.) with Linux binaries for ARM and MIPS processors?
- How can I see whether GHC is built with fully static compilation available?

---

`-static` ignored on MIPS:

```
root@debian:~# cat hello.hs
main = print 2
root@debian:~# ghc --make hello.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hello.hs, hello.o )
Linking hello ...
root@debian:~# ldd ./hello
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x77908000)
    libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5 (0x778ea000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x77855000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x7783c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x77827000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x776a0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x77675000)
    /lib/ld.so.1 (0x55550000)
root@debian:~# rm hello
root@debian:~# ghc --make -static hello.hs 
Linking hello ...
root@debian:~# ldd ./hello
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x76f98000)
    libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5 (0x76f7a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x76ee5000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x76ecc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x76eb7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x76d30000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/mips-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x76d05000)
    /lib/ld.so.1 (0x55550000)
```

---

info on GHC:

```
root@debian:~# ghc --info
 [("Project name","The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System")
 ,("GCC extra via C opts"," -fwrapv")
 ,("C compiler command","/usr/bin/gcc")
 ,("C compiler flags"," -fno-stack-protector  -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads")
 ,("ar command","/usr/bin/ar")
 ,("ar flags","q")
 ,("ar supports at file","YES")
 ,("touch command","touch")
 ,("dllwrap command","/bin/false")
 ,("windres command","/bin/false")
 ,("perl command","/usr/bin/perl")
 ,("target os","OSLinux")
 ,("target arch","ArchUnknown")
 ,("target word size","4")
 ,("target has GNU nonexec stack","True")
 ,("target has subsections via symbols","False")
 ,("Project version","7.4.1")
 ,("Booter version","7.4.1")
 ,("Stage","2")
 ,("Build platform","mips-unknown-linux")
 ,("Host platform","mips-unknown-linux")
 ,("Target platform","mips-unknown-linux")
 ,("Have interpreter","NO")
 ,("Object splitting supported","NO")
 ,("Have native code generator","NO")
 ,("Support SMP","NO")
 ,("Unregisterised","YES")
 ,("Tables next to code","YES")
 ,("RTS ways","l debug    ")
 ,("Leading underscore","NO")
 ,("Debug on","False")
 ,("LibDir","/usr/lib/ghc")
 ,("Global Package DB","/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d")
 ,("Gcc Linker flags","[\"-Wl,--hash-size=31\",\"-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads\"]")
 ,("Ld Linker flags","[\"--hash-size=31\",\"--reduce-memory-overheads\"]")
 ]
```

---

See also: [Can GHC link binaries against a libc implementation such as uclibc (used in OpenWrt by default)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270253/can-ghc-link-binaries-against-a-libc-implementation-such-as-uclibc-used-in-open)

Comment: Does `-static -optl-pthread -optl-static` help?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `-optl-static` makes sure the linker for the C libraries is told to link statically. AFAIK it also needs to be told to include pthreads then due to some ordering of the libraries being messed up. I think these flags are required for a fully static binary also on x86.

Comment: @gspr it does work! You should put that as an answer.

Comment: @gspr I will now update [`PortFusion.cabal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/PortFusion/1.2.1/PortFusion.cabal).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[In fact](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#options-linker), the `-static` flag simply tells GHC to avoid dynamic linking to *Haskell* libraries. To statically link also to the C libraries, you need to pass `-optl-pthread -optl-static` as well. The latter tells the linker to statically link to the C libraries, while the former is (AFAIK) needed due to some ordering of the linked libraries being messed up when doing this.

You need the same flags for a fully static binary on x86 as well, so this isn't specific to ARM and MIPS.

Comment: I believe having `ld-options: -static` on x86 in [`PortFusion.cabal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/PortFusion/1.2.1/PortFusion.cabal) was enough, I built and verified staticness of Linux x86-64 and x86-32 binaries without `-pthread`. Thanks for pointing both out! On ARM and MIPS `-pthread` seems to be strictly needed.