# Can GHC link binaries against a libc implementation such as uclibc (used in OpenWrt by default)?

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc, glibc, uclibc

I am using Debian/MIPS+QEMU to build [MIPS ports of PortFusion](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion/wiki/MIPS-Builds) (a TCP tunneling solution). The resulting binaries are linked against GNU libc. Thus, they cannot be just copied over and used on vanilla OpenWrt which ships with **uclibc** instead of **eglibc** (which seems binary-compatible with GNU libc).

---

- Is there a way to link Haskell/GHC binaries on Debian/MIPS against **uclibc** instead of **eglibc**?
- Can OpenWrt's using **uclibc** be really *the* reason why PortFusion binaries copied over from Debian fail to run with `-ash: binary not found` or can this message be due to something entirely else?

---

See https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion/wiki/MIPS-Builds for details on which `haskell-platform`, Linux kernel and CPU emulation are used.

---

The current head of OpenWrt's GIT repository is failing at `make` when I attempt building custom OpenWrt images that use **eglibc** instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to link Haskell/GHC binaries on Debian/MIPS against
>   uclibc instead of eglibc?

No. You need to to rebuild Haskell/GHC from sources using uclibc-based GCC cross-compiler.

> Can OpenWrt's using uclibc be really the reason

Yes. Also, you can try to use `ldd` on your MIPS pplatform to check what library is missing. I'm sure it will be some of libc-related libraries.